App deployed with Kamal and Docker down because of full memory (high load)

I have a dockerized rails 7 app deployed with Kamal.
From time to time the website goes down and I cannot find the reason.
I have a single app with low traffic app hosted on Hetzner
CX21 2 (VCPUs Intel) 4 GB (RAM) 40 GB (SSD) 20 TB (TRAFFIC)
I've tried to add various memory: 520m to deploy.yml
servers:
  web:
    hosts:
      - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX # HETZNER
    options:
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway
      memory: 512m
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.app.rule: Host(`app.fr`)
      traefik.http.routers.app.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt

  job:
    hosts:
      - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    # Or something like bin/job
    cmd: bin/bundle exec sidekiq
    # Limit workers resources
    options:
      cpus: 1
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway
      memory: 512m
# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .env).
# Remember to run `kamal env push` after making changes!
env:
  clear:
    DB_HOST: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    POSTGRES_DB: app_production
    POSTGRES_USER: app
    RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: 1
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: 1
    CHROME_HEADLESS_HOST: app-chromium
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    - REDIS_URL
builder:f  dockerfile: production.Dockerfile
  remote:
    arch: amd64  db:
    host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    image: postgres:15
    port: 5432
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_DB: app_production
        POSTGRES_USER: app
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    files:
      - db/production.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
    options:
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway
      memory: "1GB"
  redis:
    image: "redis:7"
    cmd: "/bin/sh -c 'redis-server --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD'"
    env:
      secret:
        - REDIS_PASSWORD
    roles:
      - web
      - job
    port: 6379
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/redis:/data
    options:
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway
      memory: 512m
  chromium:
    image: 'browserless/chrome:latest'
    roles:
      - web
      - job
    options:
      memory: "1GB"
      "add-host": host.docker.internal:host-gateway

traefik:
  options:
    memory: 512m
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to: websecure
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme: https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: "stephane@app.paris"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json" # Must match the path in `volume`
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint: web    # Configure custom arguments for Traefik
    accesslog: true
    accesslog.format: json
volumes:
  - storage:/rails/storage

The only solution I found so far :
ssh @server
shutdown -r now restart
then on my computer
kamal deploy -d production

Sounds like you have a memory leak— and given your docker configuration it seems like you are spinning up a browser on your server. My bet is those are not cleaning up nicely and are eating resources.

@dbugger thanks for pointing this out. it is puppeteer to print pdf by using this rubygem https://github.com/Studiosity/grover.
I will try disabling this and see how it goes
